# Selection Sort Code with srand input

Tags: c, sorting, selection-sort

My instructor put us in charge of compiling a code where we make a Selection Sort Code in C, like this one I found online,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int array[100], n, c, d, position, swap;

   printf("Enter number of elements\n");
   scanf("%d", &n);

   printf("Enter %d integers\n", n);

   for ( c = 0 ; c < n ; c++ )
      scanf("%d", &array[c]);

   for ( c = 0 ; c < ( n - 1 ) ; c++ )
   {
      position = c;

      for ( d = c + 1 ; d < n ; d++ )
      {
         if ( array[position] > array[d] )
            position = d;
      }
      if ( position != c )
      {
         swap = array[c];
         array[c] = array[position];
         array[position] = swap;
      }
   }

   printf("Sorted list in ascending order:\n");

   for ( c = 0 ; c < n ; c++ )
      printf("%d\n", array[c]);

   return 0;
}
```

Instead of inputting an array of numbers, we have to use the `srand()` command to generate a random set of numbers.

I have been at it for about 4 hours now and I just can't seem to get it.
Please I really need help with using `srand()` and `rand()`

Comment: You use [`srand()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/srand) to seed the random number generator (**once**). You use [`rand()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/rand) to actually generate the numbers. I see neither in this code so I'm not sure what has been going on for the last four hours.

Comment: your instructor, poor guy!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `srand()` is used to seed the random number generator. You can generate random numbers with `rand()`

Read this for more information

[in C, how does srand relate to rand function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21273550/in-c-how-does-srand-relate-to-rand-function)

You need to use `srand()` to seed the random number generator ( so that we get different values on each run of the program ) and use `rand()` for generating the numbers.

Instead of the `scanf()` , just use `array[c] = rand() % 100 ;` ( this produces random numbers between 0 and 99 , you can change the 100 to any other integer ). This code can be used as reference

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<time.h>                  //  for time()
#include<stdlib.h>                // for rand()
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));                       // seeding the random number generator
   int array[100], n, c, d, position, swap;

   printf("Enter number of elements\n");
   scanf("%d", &n);

   printf("Enter %d integers\n", n);

   for ( c = 0 ; c < n ; c++ )
      array[c]=rand()%100;                 // storing a random number between 0 and 100 ( Note that this might produce the same number more than once )

   for ( c = 0 ; c < ( n - 1 ) ; c++ )
   {
      position = c;

      for ( d = c + 1 ; d < n ; d++ )
      {
         if ( array[position] > array[d] )
            position = d;
      }
      if ( position != c )
      {
         swap = array[c];
         array[c] = array[position];
         array[position] = swap;
      }
   }

   printf("Sorted list in ascending order:\n");

   for ( c = 0 ; c < n ; c++ )
      printf("%d\n", array[c]);

   return 0;
}
```

I'm also adding the links from @WhozCraig 's comment because it will be useful

[srand()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/srand)

[rand()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/rand)