# c++ My random gen randomly gens something but it does it in the same order every time u run it

Tags: c++, random

So ive made a MAC Address generator. But the random part is very strange. It randomly generates a number that i use to choose something from an array. But each time you run the exe. It gens the same number.
Here is my code

```
#include <random>
#include <string>
//Mac Addr example -> 82-F5-4D-72-C1-EA
//6 two char sets
//Dont include spaces/dashes/dots

std::string chars[] = { "A","B","C","D","E","F" };
int nums[] = { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };

std::string GenMacAddr()
{
    std::string final;
    std::string CharSet;
    int choice;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        choice = 1 + rand() % 4;
        if (choice == 1) { //Char Set only int
            for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++) { //Makes action happen twice
                final += std::to_string(nums[rand()%10]);
            }
        }
        else if (choice == 2) { //Char set only str
            for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++) { //Makes action happen twice
                final += chars[rand() % 6];
            }
        }
        else if (choice == 3) {
            final += chars[rand() % 6];
            final += std::to_string(nums[rand() % 10]);
        }
        else if (choice == 4) {
            final += std::to_string(nums[rand() % 10]);
            final += chars[rand() % 6] ;
        }
    }
    
    return final;
}
```

Comment: You may get your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21273550/how-does-srand-relate-to-rand-function)

Comment: `rand()` isnt really random. It is a pseudo random generator and to get a different sequence of numbers you need to use a different seed. Do you call `srand()` somewhere?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand

Comment: In modern C++, you use <random>. Example: https://gist.github.com/Bktero/70cbcece6f001cb63814b8db49326ad6

Comment: `#include <random>` and `rand()`  have nothing to do with each other. `rand()` is from `cstdlib` header.

Comment: @Bktero That function is however not what I would recommend. Using `random_device` may be very slow since it's supposed to pick numbers from an entropy pool which may get depleated if you use it too much. You usually use `random_device` to seed a fast pseudo random number generator instead.

Comment: You need to call srand() one time in your `int main()` before using `rand()`. And I mean 1 time. Some users make the mistake of calling it every time then ask why all their "random" numbers are the same.

Comment: Btw I don't know if that's intentional, but your algorithm could be [way shorter](https://godbolt.org/z/nc4ce1).

Comment: @TedLyngmo thanks for this information, I am learning something! I have updated my gist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

rand() is a deterministic random number generator . In order to achieve actual pseudo-random results you should first seed it with something like `srand(time(NULL))` .

If you look around this you will realize that this is a bad approach and you should instead give up rand() altogether , instead use `<random>` from C++11 . Stephan T. Lavavej has a really nice talk about it , you should see it [here](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) .

Here is also the code snippet he recommends from that talk .

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::random_device random_dev; // (Non?) deterministic random number generator
    std::mt19937 mers_t(random_dev()); // Seed mersenne twister with it .
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0, 100); // Bound the output.

    // Print a random integer in the range [0,100] ( included ) .
    std::cout << distribution(mers_t) << '\n';
}
```

EDIT:
As François noted, std::random_device isn't required to be non-deterministic and it's actually implementation dependent.
One indication to tell if it is or not is by checking the value of `entropy()` method call but then again some implementations return just a fixed value. In that case you might consider using `std::chrono` to generate a seed the way Ted describes.

Comment: Note that `std::random_device` isn't required to be non-deterministic. It should be if possible but it is not required to.

Comment: being deterministic isnt *the big* disadvantage `rand()`, often this is a very desirable feature, its also not the reason `rand()` is discouraged

Answer (score 3):

`rand()` is a *pseudo* random number generator. It will generate numbers according to an algorithm designed to have a long period (before it starts repeating itself) - but it needs a starting point. This is called *the seed*. You seed `rand()` with the `srand()` function and you should only seed it *once* during the program's execution. Seeding is often done with `time` but since `time` commonly returns whole seconds (since the epoch) you risk using the same seed if you start the program more than once (within a second).

You could instead use `std::random_device` to generate the seed if it has entropy and use a time based seed only as a fallback.

Example:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

unsigned seed() { // a function to generate a seed
    std::random_device rd;
    if(rd.entropy() > 0.) return rd(); // if random_device has entropy, use it

    // fallback, use duration since the epoch
    auto dse = (std::chrono::steady_clock::now() -
                std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point{}).count();

    return static_cast<std::make_unsigned_t<decltype(dse)>>(dse);
}

std::string GenMacAddr() {
    static const char chars[] = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7',
                                 '8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F'};

    std::string result(6 * 2, ' ');

    for(char& ch : result) ch = chars[std::rand() % std::size(chars)];
    
    return result;
}

int main() {
    std::srand(seed());   // seed rand()

    // generate 10 mac addresses
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) std::cout << GenMacAddr() << '\n';
}
```

That said, you could use one of the more modern pseudo random number generators, like `std::mt19937`, instead of `rand()` and use `std::uniform_int_distribution` instead of the modulus operation:

```
template<class PRNG = std::mt19937>
auto& prng() {
    // same seed() function as in the previous example:
    thread_local PRNG prng_instance(seed());
    return prng_instance;
}

std::string GenMacAddr() {
    static const char chars[] = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7',
                                 '8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F'};
    thread_local std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned> dist(0, std::size(chars) - 1);

    std::string result(6 * 2, ' ');

    for(char& ch : result) ch = chars[dist(prng())];
    
    return result;
}
```