# What happens when you use srand with no arguments?

Tags: perl, random

The question is pretty straightforward. What exactly happens when you use "srand" with no arguments? What is the expected behavior?

```
srand();
my $x1 = int(rand(65536)) % 65536;
my $x2 = int(rand(65536)) % 65536;
print "$x1\n";
print "$x2\n";
```

Comment: `man srand` sayeth `If no seed value is provided, the rand() function is automatically seeded with a value of 1.` (presumably applies to srand too)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21273550/how-does-srand-relate-to-rand-function

Comment: What do you think is happening? Note that you already have a number below 65536, so you don't need to take the modulus.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/srand):

> When called with a parameter, "srand" uses that for the seed; otherwise it (semi-)randomly chooses a seed.

Comment: You're right and I'm wrong. I missed the `perl` tag